# Query the current users information

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

This is using Parse btw.

I have information saved into the users class using this code here

```
-(IBAction)saveButtonAction:(id)sender {

PFUser *currentUserSave = [PFUser currentUser];

userBioString = userBio.text;
genderFieldString = genderField.text;
ageFieldString = ageField.text;

currentUserSave[@"userBioParse"] = userBioString;
currentUserSave[@"userGenderParse"] = genderFieldString;
currentUserSave[@"ageFieldParse"] = ageFieldString;

[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
[[PFUser currentUser] fetch];
```

Now I am trying to call back the information using a query. I researched how to do it and this is my result as of now.

```
-(IBAction) userProfileQuery {

NSString *bioQueryString = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"userBioParse"];
userBio.text = bioQueryString;

NSString *ageQueryString = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"ageFieldParse"];
ageField.text = ageQueryString;

NSString *genderQueryString = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"genderFieldParse"];
genderField.text = genderQueryString;
```

the information is being saved into the users class successfully. I am just unsure how to retrieve it... Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way to get the currentUsers information in parse. Try this code out. Its the most complicated one, but reading the code its easier to understand what you are doning.

```
PFQuery *query= [PFUser query];  
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser]username]];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){
    if (!error) {       
        userBio.text = [object valueForKey:@"userBioParse"];
        ageField.text = [object valueForKey:@"ageFieldParse"];
        genderField.text = [object valueForKey:@"genderFieldParse"];
    }
    else {
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

If you are doing it the way you are doing it, try, thats a litte bit of a shortcut:

```
PFUser *user = [[PFUser currentUser];
userBio.text = user.userBioParse;
```

Parse already gives you most of the code for currentUser. And the fastest way to get currentUser information that parse offers is:

```
userBio.text = currentUser.userBioParse;
```

Comment: Oops sorry about that! Seems as if I answered my own question. So the above code is valid I just misplaced the [self userProfileQuery]. Although i do appreciate the answer. I think ill be using your error message. :)! Thanks bro.

Comment: Yes looking at your code it should work. I edited my answer to explain it a little bit more. Chears!